# Polynomial factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

Why must $x^2 + x + 1$ be a factor of  $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$?

I know that when we divide  $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x^3+1$ we get $x^2 + x + 1$, but is there an argument/theorem or anything that could tell that $x^2+x+1$ must divide $x^2 + x + 1$?

Comment: Must divide $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ by $x^3+1$ instead of $x^2+x+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you count as telling. It follows from an easy, basic manipulation of familiar identities, but I don’t see any way to recognize this without appealing to something at least somewhat computational. I look at the sum $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and immediately think of $x^6-1$, and from there it all falls out:

$$\begin{align*}
x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1&=\frac{x^6-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{(x^3)^2-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{(x^3-1)(x^3+1)}{x-1}\\
&=(x^3+1)\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}\\
&=(x^3+1)(x^2+x+1)\;,
\end{align*}$$

all using standard factorizations.

Comment: Is *Division Algorithm for F[x]* makes the OP sure for dividing? He wanted to know that.

Answer (score 0):

$(x^2+x+1)(x-1)=x^3-1$ and $(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-1)=x^6-1$. Then note that $x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)$. Thus in effect it is the third binmoial formula.